# table-cell display doesn't center the contents

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an ordered list(`<ol>`) that displays a horizontal button pane.

To avoid the button items displayed vertically, i am using the property, `display: table-cell;`. But, now all items are displayed towards the left end.

The jsfiddle is @http://jsfiddle.net/42xt001j/

A snapshot -

[image]

How can i ensure, each one of the menu item takes up one third of the `ol` width?

Adding an extra property `width:33%` realigns the items in a vertical fashion, which is not desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `display: table` on the container `<ol>`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/42xt001j/1/)

```css
li {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  color: blue;
  border-color: #000000;
}
ol {
  float: left;
  width: 27em;
  border: 4px solid black;
  margin: 5em auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
li:last-child {
  border-right-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Save suite</li>
  <li>Load suite</li>
  <li>Run suite</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in css which i mention follow.

```
li {
   display: table-cell;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  color: blue;
  border-color: #000000;
}
ol{
  display:table;  
  width: 27em;
  border: 4px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  Padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
li:last-child {
  border-right-width: 0;
}
```